# cd to target folder after copying?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

This could be quite a simple one, but I can't find any answer for it.

If I am in a terminal and use the `cp` command, is there a way of instantly `cd`ing to the target directory? For example, is there some equivalent to `cp foo/file.ext ../bar/subdir/; cd ../bar/subdir/` that doesn't require retyping the path to the target folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
cp foo/file.ext ../bar/subdir/
```

followed by:

```
cd !$
```

But this won't work in one line, like `cp foo/file.ext ../bar/subdir/; cd !$`.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for (it being on one line wasn't really a factor, just wrote it like that to keep the question neat). Ta very much!